# Tornado concurrency errors running multiple processes together with a process pool executor

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, tornado, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to run multiple processes and at the same time use the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to run CPU intensive jobs. The first few requests are happily served, but then a `KeyError` is raised from `concurrent.futures.process`, and the server hangs.

Is this a bug in Tornado?

This is the simplest form I stripped the code to.

server:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
server runs 2 processes and does job on a ProcessPoolExecutor
"""
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
import tornado.options
import tornado.httpserver

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(1)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        num = int(self.request.body)
        result = yield self.executor.submit(pow, num, 2)
        self.finish(str(result))


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    server.bind(8888)
    server.start(2)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
client
"""
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


@coroutine
def remote_compute(num):
    rsp = yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8888', method='POST', body=str(num))
    print 'result:', rsp.body


IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: remote_compute(10))
```

error traceback

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/cliffxuan/.virtualenvs/executor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 216, in _queue_management_worker
    work_item = pending_work_items[result_item.work_id]
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to the interaction between `tornado` and `concurrent.futures` when you start the `tornado` server with multiple processes, using `server.start(2)`. This internally uses `os.fork()` to create the two processes. Because you're declaring the `Executor` as a class variable, it gets instantiated when the `MainHandler` class itself is executed, prior to `server.start()` actually running. That means that both processes end up sharing a single  (albeit forked) `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance. This leads to some oddities - each process gets copy-on-write versions of most data structures inside the `Executor`, but they end up actually sharing the same worker processes.

`ProcessPoolExecutor` doesn't support being shared between processes like this, so have the problems you see when the second process tries to use the `Executor`. You can work around it by only creating the `Executor` *after* the `fork` has occurred:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = None # None for now

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        num = int(self.request.body)
        result = yield self.executor.submit(pow, num, 2)
        self.finish(str(result))


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    server.bind(8889)
    server.start(2) # We fork here
    MainHandler.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(1) # Now we can create the Executor
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```